# How to stream live audio and video while keeping low latency

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live, rtsp

I'm writing a program similar to StreamMyGame with the difference of the client being free and more importantly, open source, so I can port it to other devices (in my case an OpenPandora), or even make an html5 or flash client.

Because the objective of the program is to stream video games, **latency should be reduced to a minimum**.

Right now I can capture video of Direct 3D 9 games at a fixed frame rate, encode it using libx264 and dumping it to disk, and send input remotely, but I'm stumped at sending the video and eventually the audio through the network.

I don't want to implement a way just to discover that it introduces several seconds of delay and I don't care how it is done as long as it is done.

Off of my head I can think several ways:

- My current way, encode video with libx264 and audio with lame or as ac3 and send them with live555 as a RTSP feed, though the library is not playing nice with MSVC and I’m still trying to understand its functioning.
- Have the ffmpeg library do all the grunt work, where it encodes and sends (I guess I'll have to use ffserver to get an idea on how to do it)
- Same but using libvlc, perhaps hurting encoding configurability in the process.
- Using several pipes with the independent programs (ie: piping data to x264.exe or ffmpeg.exe)
- Use other libraries such as [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) or [JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib) that might simplify the process.
- The hard way, sending video and audio through an UDP channel and figuring out how to synchronizing everything at the client (though the reason to use RTSP is to avoid this).
- Your way, if I didn't think of something.

The second option would really be the best as it would reduce the number of libraries (integrate swscale, libx264, the audio codec and the sender library), simplify the development and bringing more codec variety (CELT looks promising) but I worry about latency as it might have a longer pipeline.

100 ms would already be too much, especially when you consider you might be adding another 150 ms of latency when it is used trough broadband.

Does any of you have experience with these libraries, to recommend me to switch to ffmpeg, keep wrestling live555 or do anything else (even if I didn’t mentioned it)?

Answer (score 0):

I had very good results of streaming large blocks of data with low latency using UDT4 library. But first I would suggest checking ffmpegs network capabilities, so you have a native solution in all operations.

Comment: That library would be interesting if I needed a reliable connection as well, but I don't. It is just video, if I skip a couple of bytes or an entire frame, the frame is going to look distorted or a short sequence until the next keyframe at worst.
ffserver looks like it could fit the bill, but the comments inside the source shows that even the developers are not very confident of their own code which makes me somewhat weary.
Do you have experience with the latter about latencies?

Comment: UDT4 is a guaranteed delivery lib for a reliable transfer, dont know where you got that

Comment: Sorry if I edited too slow (I hit enter accidentally) or wasn’t clear. I don’t need reliability, which is why raw UDP would work just as well.
Though, if I go UDP I might end up using it as I’ll appreciate the packet reordering features and the simplicity of use.

Comment: In my case the latencies transferring 1MByte data windows at 30fps were only 4ms to 1ms in 1Gb LAN. Data comes preordered, so you dont have any ordering issues too. Simple and reliable as that.